# Merge properties of a list to another based on properties objects

Tags: kotlin, data-structures

I got 2 lists with x objects inside , for example:

```
data class Model(
    var token: String = "",
    var id: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var image: Int = 0,
)
```

array is initialized and filled, the other list has  x objects also that contains the objects of the first list but with different values in their properties!

what I want to do is to change the properties of the first array by the second one if they got the same object.name

```
var arr1 = ArrayList<Model>() // locale  
var arr2 = ArrayList<Model>() // from db
```

the first array I got for example

```
[Model(name = "David", token = "" , image = 0)]
```

the second array I got

```
[Model(name = "David", token = "1asd5asdd851", image = 1)]
```

*How do I make the first array take the missing token?*

I tried with `.filter{}` and with `.map{}`. `groupBy {}` for hours because Name is the only properties that are the same but I'm more and more confused.

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little bit better? Some examples and maybe some actual code would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Is `name` guaranteed to be unique across all objects in the list?

Comment: Yes, I edited my code @broot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first group the second array by name using [associateBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate-by.html) and then iterate over first array and reassign properties:

```kotlin
val arr2ByName = arr2.associateBy { it.name }
arr1.forEach { item1 ->
    arr2ByName[item1.name]?.let { item2 ->
        item1.token = item2.token
        item1.image = item2.image
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to modify items in `arr1`, but create another array and you can use items from both `arr1` and `arr2`, then it will be much easier:

```kotlin
val arr3 = arr1.map { arr2ByName[it.name] ?: it }
```

Comment: I prefer  to use `arr1` and not creating another variable,  when debugging I see the code doesn't reach the `.let { }` of the ``arr2ByName`` , I checked on my side, and each of the arrays has the exact `name` variable

Comment: that's strange all the  arr2 got tokens, but when I try to re assign it to the first array , its empty.. I printed the ``arr2`` 's keys , and I got an empty [] . how is that possible?

Comment: Please recheck everything. It works: https://pl.kotl.in/771_iBab7

Comment: Yes, the error was from me, I misspelled l and I

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to use [fold()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) as follows:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val arr1 = listOf(Model(name = "David", token = "" , image = 0))
    val arr2 = listOf(Model(name = "David", token = "1asd5asdd851", image = 1))

    val mergedModels = arr2.fold(arr1) { localModels, dbModel ->
        localModels.map { localModel ->
            if (localModel.name == dbModel.name) localModel.copy(token = dbModel.token, image = dbModel.image)
            else localModel
        }
    }

    println(mergedModels)
}
```

If you want to reuse `arr1` variable then you can do the following (but I would still use the previous option):

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var arr1 = listOf(Model(name = "David", token = "" , image = 0))
    val arr2 = listOf(Model(name = "David", token = "1asd5asdd851", image = 1))

    arr1 = arr2.fold(arr1) { localModels, dbModel ->
        localModels.map { localModel ->
            if (localModel.name == dbModel.name) localModel.copy(token = dbModel.token, image = dbModel.image)
            else localModel
        }
    }

    println(arr1)
}
```